# How to represent inputs in a neural network?

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to  build and train a neural network to recognize letters of the alphabet and numbers based upon their design using a seven segment display where each segment of the display is one input into the neural network ( I am using the basic prop simulator).

I am just a bit unsure about of how to represent the input values in the pattern file. I understand that I need to have the inputs (0-9 and the alphabet A-H) and then the output should be the binary of the ASCII code.

I could convert 0-9 to binary but then I am unsure about the letters ( A-H) how would I represent this in the pattern file?

```
Character           ASCII           Neural Network Output (Binary)

0                      48                    0110000
1                      49                    0110001
2                      50                    0110010
3                      51                    0110011
4                      52                    0110100
5                      53                    0110101
6                      54                    0110110
7                      55                    0110111
8                      56                    0111000
9                      57                    0111001
A                      65                    1000001
B                      66                    1000010
C                      67                    1000011
D                      68                    1000100
E                      69                    1000101
F                      70                    1000110
H                      72                    1001000
```

Thank you for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent all 26 letters (assuming you're dealing with the English alphabet) and 10 digits with a binary code. This is not an issue, IMO. IF I understood correctly, you want to map an \mathbb{R}^7 input vector to an \mathbb{R}^36 output vector (probably using a softmax output layer).

I believe you'd be better off by following the standard convention in the machine learning / neural network / deep learning communities: treat this problem as a image recognition problem, that is, feed the network with a (L x W) vector of pixel intensities (assuming a L x W sized image, in pixels) and training a NN (convolutional networks seem to be rather well suited for this) with a softmax output layer ("softmax" is a fancy name for multinomial logit).

In the following link you can find a lengthier explanation:  https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/beginners/

The MNIST problem is the "Hello, world!" of deep learning and there are tons of examples/implementations on the web.